# Replace each element of the array in String.replace

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I need to replace all characters of an incoming string with the corresponding ones from an object, how can I do this using an array?

```js
function handleCyrillic(str) {
  const obj = {
    й: "\\'e9",
    ц: "\\'f6",
  };
  let res = "";

  const arr = Object.keys(obj);
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(item, "gi");
    res += str.replace(regex, function (s) {
      return s
        .split("")
        .map((n) => (n = obj[n]))
        .join("");
    });
  });
  return res;
}
console.log(handleCyrillic("цй  йй!!"));
```

> I get in the console `ц\'e9  \'e9\'e9!!\'f6й  йй!!`
> I expected `\'f6\'e9  \'e9\'e9!!`

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is that `n = obj[n]` is an assignment statement. What are you expecting to return in your `map()`? Do you want `filter()` instead?

Comment: Via map i want to replace characters in a string

Comment: Your map sets the variable `n`, but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for this conversion table in the first place. Basic Unicode Cyrillic is continuous in range 410...44f and Win-1251 is c0..ff, so you can just do some codepoint arithmetics to convert between both:

```js
function handleCyrillic(str) {
    let res = ''

    for (let chr of str) {
        let cp = chr.codePointAt(0)
        if (0x410 <= cp && cp <= 0x44f)
            res += "\\'" + (cp - 0x410 + 0xc0).toString(16)
        else
            res += chr
    }
    
    return res;
}

console.log(handleCyrillic("цй  йй!!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `join` your `obj` keys and surround with square brackets for the `or` condition and in the `replace` method callback replaces the match string with the corresponding replacement in the `obj`.

```js
function handleCyrillic(str) {
  const obj = {
    й: "\\'e9",
    ц: "\\'f6",
  };

  const arr = Object.keys(obj);
  const regex = new RegExp(`[${arr.join()}]`, "gi");
  return str.replace(regex, function(s) {
    return obj[s]
  });    
}
console.log(handleCyrillic("цй  йй!!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `res` variable is being overwritten each time a character is replaced instead of appending the replacement to the result. This is updated and a bit refactored version:

```
function handleCyrillic(str) {
  const obj = {
    й: "\\'e9",
    ц: "\\'f6",
  };
  let res = str;

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(key, "gi");
    res = res.replace(regex, obj[key]);
  });

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. At first split the string. If a character exists as a key in the obj, map() returns the obj value, if not it returns the current character. In the end join the string.

```js
function handleCyrillic(str) {
  const obj = {
    й: "\\'e9",
    ц: "\\'f6",
  };
  
  return str.split('').map(char => obj[char] || char).join('');
}

console.log(handleCyrillic("цй йй!!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are replacing on the **str** which is parameter which never going to be change and you are concate that into the **res** which is function return variable that's why you are not getting desired output

```
function handleCyrillic(str) {
  const obj = {
    й: "\\'e9",
    ц: "\\'f6",
  };
  let res = str;

  const arr = Object.keys(obj);
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(item, "gi");
    res = res.replace(regex,obj[item]);
  });
  return res;
}
console.log(handleCyrillic("цй  йй!!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a regular expression here. You can use `Array.from` with its callback:

```js
const obj = {
    й: "\\'e9",
    ц: "\\'f6",
};
const handleCyrillic = str => Array.from(str, ch => obj[ch] ?? ch).join("");

console.log(handleCyrillic("цй йй!!"));
```

The `??` operator deals with cases where there is no mapping for a character. This still allows a mapping to the empty string to be included in `obj`, which means you want to *remove* a character.